# error while installing npm error for version

Tags: react-native, npm-install

I am trying to install npm to the code i am facing the below issue.

Command i try : `npm install`

or

```
npm -g install npm
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
```

below is the error:

```
sh: patch-package: command not found
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path XXXX
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c patch-package
```

Comment: It mentions the error in log
```patch-package: command not found```
You need to install that package

Answer (score -1):

If you're using yarn you can run `yarn patch-package <args>`

Otherwise `./node_modules/.bin/patch-package <args>`

Or add `./node_modules/.bin` to your $PATH environment variable (I prefer doing this)